# When I call someone using Google Hangouts do they pay long distance?

Tags: google-hangouts, phone-number, voip

I'm a Canadian living in the UK. I recently discovered that Google Hangouts allows free calls to (some) North American landlines. I just made calls to my Canadian bank and my Canadian cable company with no issues. I'd like to use it to call my grandmother.

My question is: **How will my grandmother be billed?**

I doubt it matters where I'm calling from (I doubt she'll have to pay for an incoming long distance call from the UK) but will she have to pay for long distance from California, where Google is based?

I Googled it but all I could find was that on the caller ID when a phone gets called by Google Hangouts it shows up as "Unknown". (Source: https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3187125?hl=e)

Comment: Unless you're calling collect, recipients don't pay for incoming calls.

Comment: @AlE. I don't think that's always the case. I spoke with Bell Canada before I moved and they said that if a UK number called my Bell mobile, I would have to pay something ridiculous like $0.40/minute.